# How to avoid Upwork scams

Tags: qa-developer

Has anyone been a freelancer on Upwork.com? 
Is this site a legit remote work place?
I don't want to get identity theft from sharing my info and my computer.
I need experience to showcase I can do automation work though and I am passed the internship age. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about quality assurance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because - better asked at https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/ and there might be answers: search before asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't gotten any gigs or even emails from my profile on upwork.com personally
even though I have over 5 years of experience in QA and get tons of emails and phone calls from my linkedin profile. Perhaps my asking rate is too high. Try going with a very low asking rate if you really need a gig.

Scammers are not only targeting you via emails or lucrative ads, they are also common on Upwork (formerly oDesk), Freelancer.com and other freelancing marketplaces. If you are not cautious, it is easy to fall prey to scams on Upwork or Freelancer. Scammers will get their jobs done by you and then disappear without paying you for your efforts. Besides legitimate projects, there are several types of scams on online job portals. Let’s see how to avoid them.

- Read the Project Description Attentively - Legitimate buyers would always make their requirements clear in the job description.
- A reliable client should have a payment method verified with the marketplace.
- Never agree to provide a free sample – some scammers are exploring the web to trick the newbie freelancers to get their works done at zero cost.
- For your newer clients, demand up-front payments or escrow protections for fixed priced jobs. Major online freelancing sites provide escrow systems to prevent payment disputes. There are hourly contracts where you can use official time tracker apps provided by freelance marketplaces to log your job related activities and get paid automatically.
- You can detect a scam job post just by reading its description, checking the client details and finally conversing with the prospective buyer.

Upwork provides you with three ways you can choose to bill your clients:

- Hourly billing
- Fixed-price billing
- Pre-funded milestone payment

Upwork has several payment methods including:

- Direct Deposit
- PayPal
- Wire Transfer
- Local Funds Transfer
- Payoneer
- Skrill

How do I get hired at Upwork with no experience?

- Always use the ‘’no experience required’’ filter while looking for jobs, instead of competing with experienced freelancers.
- Set your hourly rate as low as reasonably possible. Keep in mind that with Upwork, if you accept to get paid less than you are worth, you will eventually get paid more than you are worth. Work on your reputation first and with time, your reputation will land work for you.
- Don’t hold anything back. Furbish your profile with each and every skill, experience and accomplishments you have, even if you are not sure about them. In the first place, clients will check out your hourly rate, before they get to your skills.
- Take the inbuilt proficiency tests. Each area of expertise has tests that once you pass, will improve your chances of landing jobs.
- Make your profile as authentic as you possibly can. If English is not your native language, don’t say that it is. It’s easier than you think to spot a liar, and this could make its way to your public profile, from the start!

Upwork hacks, tips and tricks:

- Mind your time zone. If most of the clients you work for live on the opposite side of the world, adjust your working timetable to match their daily routine. For example, most clients will post jobs in the morning and before retiring for the night.
- Avoid back and forth with clients. Be as interactive as possible with the client before starting the job. Clients hate getting half-baked work. All in all, ensure everything is in the clear before you start working.
- Don’t come across as desperate. It’s ill-advised to set your rates high in the beginning. It’s also misguided to set your price too low.
- Be easy to get in touch with. Keep your email notification sounds on and always be prompt while replying to clients’ messages.
- Don’t wait for work to come to you. Be reasonably aggressive while looking for work. For instance, send as many proposals as possible and don’t be quick to throw in the towel.
- Create a proven online portfolio. Provide proof wherever necessary of the skills and experiences you indicated in your resume. Showcase your actual work to clients, and remove the speculative bit of your proposal.
- Make your profile error-free. Your profile includes your resume and cover letter. All these are the first things potential clients will see even before you get the chance to interact with them. For example, grammar, spelling and texting lingo should be close to perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I personally took on 1 or 2 small jobs on Upwork last year. No issues with identity theft or anything of the sort. Just be careful with what you share with potential clients.